# Branch not merged properly into master in Git

Tags: git, github, merge

I was on `master` branch and unfortunately, I run the command `git pull origin DEV13-ConsumerReport-20190827` which is created from master, it merged into `master` automatically. The branch `DEV13-ConsumerReport-20190827` was not stable at that time. then I run command to revert back to Head. after that `master` was stabled. after working on `DEV13-ConsumerReport-20190827` when I want to merge it into `master`, it was not merged properly.
I repeat the process again, I revert to Head in the `master` branch, then I again merge `DEV13-ConsumerReport-20190827` into master. the status shows `already updated`. but code was mashed up and not merge properly.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516743/github-does-not-recognize-changes-from-a-reverted-pull-request/41516882#41516882

Comment: Thanks, @JohnSzakmeister. I got solution by running this command. `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Be careful with that... if you're sharing the repo with others, then you could be setting yourself up for a mess of a problem to clean up.  The better way would be to "revert the revert".  It avoids modifying history on other users, which is a big plus when working with others.

Comment: Ok, got it @JohnSzakmeister Thanks